# How can I install gcc-4.2 g++-4.2 on Linux Mint 17 with gcc-4.8 already installed?

Tags: linux-mint, gcc, aptitude

I need an older version of gcc (specifically 4.2) alongside current gcc (4.8) on Linux Mint 17.
Default Mint repositories can't find needed package:

```
sudo aptitude install gcc-4.2
No candidate version found for gcc-4.2
```

1. what lines should I add to `/etc/apt/sources.list` so that after `sudo aptitude update` proper packages could be downloaded
2. after accomplishing the above how can I install gcc-4.2 tool chain without a collision with existing gcc-4.8 (so to use gcc-4.2 by invoking `gcc` command)